# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined angularjs:11592

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute, route-provider, ionic-framework

I am using ionic and get this error message, when switiching between my tabs:
The error only occurs when switching the tabs and I have got no clue where it might come from:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at Object.ngIfWatchAction [as fn] (http://localhost:8100/lib/angular/angular.js:23476:47)
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:8100/lib/angular/angular.js:14223:29)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:8100/lib/angular/angular.js:14486:24)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/release/js/ionic-angular.js:8873:20)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.eventHandler (http://localhost:8100/lib/angular/angular.js:3009:21)
    at triggerMouseEvent (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/release/js/ionic.js:2641:7)
    at tapClick (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/release/js/ionic.js:2630:3)
    at HTMLDocument.tapMouseUp (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/release/js/ionic.js:2700:5)angular.js:11592 (anonymous function)angular.js:8542 (anonymous function)angular.js:14241 Scope.$digestangular.js:14486 Scope.$applyionic-angular.js:8873 (anonymous function)angular.js:3009 eventHandlerionic.js:2641 triggerMouseEventionic.js:2630 tapClickionic.js:2700 tapMouseUp
```

I think it probably has got something to do with my app.js, where I handle the routing:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngAnimate', 'home', 'play', 'settings', 'chatMaster', 'registration', 'login', 'angular.css.injector', 'map', 'coins'])

.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
})

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, cssInjectorProvider) {

    // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
    // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
    // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
    // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
    $stateProvider

    // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
        url: "/tab",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
    })

    .state('login', {
        url: "/login",
        templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
        data: {
            css: 'styles/login.css'
        }
    })

    .state('registration', {
        url: "/registration",
        templateUrl: "templates/registration.html",
    })

    // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

    .state('tab.home', {
        url: '/home',
        views: {
            'tab-home': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/tab-home.html',
                controller: 'homeCtrl'
            }
        }
    })

    .state('tab.play-screen', {
        url: '/play-screen',
        views: {
            'tab-home': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/play-screen.html',
                controller: 'playCtrl',
            }
        }
    })

    .state('tab.map', {
        url: '/play-screen/map',
        views: {
            'tab-home': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/map.html',
                controller: 'mapCtrl'
            }

        }
    })

    .state('tab.chat-master', {
        url: '/chat-master',
        views: {
            'tab-chat-master': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chat-master.html',
                controller: 'chatMasterCtrl'
            }
        }
    })

    .state('tab.coins', {
        url: '/coins',
        views: {
            'tab-coins': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/tab-coins.html',
                controller: 'coinsCtrl'
            }
        }
    })

    .state('tab.settings', {
        url: '/settings',
        views: {
            'tab-settings': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/tab-settings.html',
                controller: 'settingsCtrl'
            }
        }
    });

    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('login');

    //After a page change all injected CSS files are removed
    cssInjectorProvider.setSinglePageMode(true);
});
```

I really hope that you can find anything or at least give me a clue where to look at.

Thanks! :)

Comment: .then is only a function of a promise. so somewhere in your code you have a promise, but at whatever point, the promise is undefined.

Comment: Can you replicate in a plunker?

Comment: You don't actually call `.then` in the code you provided.  Please provide more relevant code.

Comment: Can you show the HTML for the tabs?

Comment: I do not know whats relevant to it as well.
Here is my reposetory https://github.com/chrizzTs/Who-U 
Maybe this helps to get a deeper view of it.

Comment: It could also be an event handler of an ionic popup. @OP: It takes a lot of effort to checkout your repository and do the search for you. So please give us some more relevant code. Search for ".then" in your code and let us know the files where it occurs.